# The Choice Mode Multiple Modal does not working properly in Dialog Fragment Android

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I have a ListView on a Fragment
I select an item and I get a Dialog Fragment
This Dialog fragment has a ListView with some Answers, an EditText and a Dismiss Button

**When I try to select multiple items as answers I need first to make a tap in the list. Why is that? The same happens even if: I use setOnItemLongClickListener or setOnItemClickListener**

The following is in onViewCreated and on setOnItemLongClickListener

```
AnswerList.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            AnswerList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
            Log.d("Select Item",String.valueOf(position));
            AnswerList.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener()
            {

                @Override
                public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu)
                {
                    mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu)
                {


                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item)
                {
                    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_settings){
                        SparseBooleanArray selected = mAdapter.getSelectedIds();
                        short size = (short)selected.size();
                        for (byte I = 0; I<size; I++){
                            if (selected.valueAt(I)) {
                                String selectedItem = mAdapter.getItem(selected.keyAt(I));

                            }
                        }


                        // Close CAB (Contextual Action Bar)
                        mode.finish();
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode)
                {

                }

                @Override
                public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position, long id, boolean checked)
                {
                    // Prints the count of selected Items in title
                    mode.setTitle(AnswerList.getCheckedItemCount() + " Selected");


                    // Toggle the state of item after every click on it
                    mAdapter.toggleSelection(position);
                }
            });
```

The part of the ListView in the DialogFragment XML

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        android:id="@+id/AnswerList"
        android:layout_margin="4dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Show please your xml layout

Answer (score 0):

The

```
AnswerList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
        Log.d("Select Item",String.valueOf(position));
        AnswerList.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener()
        {
....
}
```

must be outside not nested in OnItemLongClickListener